# Is it possible using the ifcplusplus library to convert the geometry of an .ifc file into coordinates for further conversion to .stl format?

Tags: c++, stl, lib, ifc

There is a task to convert the .ifc format to .stl using the c++ library, I am considering all possible options, the ifcopenshell library is not suitable.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.